# SBT sub-sub projects don't work?

Tags: scala, sbt

I have a build that looks like this

`thing/
  build.sbt
  clientserver/
    build.sbt
    client/
      ...
    server/
      ...`

`//build.sbt
val clientserver = project.in(file("clientserver"))...`

`//clientserver/build.sbt
val client = project.in(file("client"))...
val server = project.in(file("server"))...`

How can I reference these sub-sub projects in the SBT console? `clientserver/client/compile` or `clientserver.client/compile` don't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All project definitions must be defined in the top-level build. However, you can very well have projects whose base directories are 2 levels deep.

Hence, for your example, you should have something like the following in `thing/build.sbt`:

```
lazy val clientserver = project.in(file("clientserver"))...

lazy val clientserverClient = project.in(file("clientserver/client"))...
lazy val clientserverServer = project.in(file("clientserver/server"))...
```

In the sbt console, they are therefore refercenced as `clientserverClient` and `clientserverServer`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

How do you use sbt? Meaning, through IDE or command line? I had problems with my multi module project in IntelliJ but recent updates resolved my problem.

The updates included IntelliJ itself (from 13.3 to 14.0) and scala-plugin to 1.1 version.

When I used to run my project from not IDE everything worked out smoothly but when I switched to IntelliJ it was auto creating modules scala facets and what made it not compile-able. Second problem was with folders names that contained space char - UriException. Both updates resolved issues.

Could you check if it works from cmd line? If so, could you put all sub modules definitions to 'thing/build.sbt' and try it out? I define my project as in snippet below but in Scala object (extends Build trait) and it works like a charm.

```
lazy val root = Project(
    id = "root",
    file ("."),
    settings = buildSettings
              ++ Seq (description := "root")
              ++ Seq (libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies)
    ) aggregate core

lazy val core = Project(
    id = "Core",
    base = file ("Core module"),
    settings = buildSettings
              ++ Seq (description := "Core desc")
              ++ Seq (libraryDependencies ++= commonDependencies)
    )
```